# Spark Error: Partition column type should be numeric, date, or timestamp, but string found

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to read data from Oracle table using Scala in Spark.My partition column type is **string** and Spark version is 3.1.2. My code is in the following:

```
object test_parallelize extends App {
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .master("local[4]")
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "8g")
    .config("spark.executor.cores", 4)
    .config("spark.task.cpus",1)
    .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
    .config("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled", false) 
    .getOrCreate()

 val jdbcDF = spark.read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521:orcldb")
    .option("dbtable", "mytable")
    .option("user", "test")
    .option("password", "*******")
    .option("numPartitions",4)
    .option("partitionColumn","C_NUM")
    .option("lowerBound",1)
    .option("upperBound",10000)
    .load()

   jdbcDF.show()
```

When I run it , receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Partition column type should be numeric, date, or timestamp, but string found
```

I had known about the error, it is because *C_NUM* is **VARCHAR**;so, I searched and found this point in Spark Site:

```
For these use cases, the automatic type inference can be configured by **spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled**, which is default to true. When type inference is disabled, string type will be used for the partitioning columns.
```

So I added this line in my code:

```
config("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled", "false")
```

But nothing is changed. Still I receive the same error.

Would you please tell how to solve the issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The column "C_NUM" in your example is of **string** type? well the error is self explanatory that you need a numeric column instead of string, as that property is used by spark to divide your rows between different parallel process that are reading from the source.

you can refer the property definition here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#data-source-option

Comment: @Pradeepyadav, thanks for your feedback. I have known about the error and the link. I want to know about where I can set **spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled** in Spark.

Comment: Then there are couple of things I can think off, you might have already tried.
1. try config("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled", false) /*notice: the boolean value without quotes*/
2. try spark.conf.set method and try printing them too using spark.conf.get("property.name") ---> (just for debugging)
3. try passing the parameter using --conf in the spark-submit command.

Comment: @Pradeepyadav, I tested **config("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled", false) ** without quotes, but still the same error. Also, I used **spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled",false)**, nothing is changed. I'll test the third way and print the **property.name**. Thank you very much.

Comment: if nothing works, try hardcoding the settings in spark-defaults.conf or set/modify the property in spark-env.sh and restart the spark application.